# Can my SONY ICD-UX533 be used as an external microphone to improve my GoPro sound quality?

Tags: sony, external

I'm trying to devise a solution for recording better audio for my GoPro Hero4 Silver, using an external mic. Before going out and blowing my money on new hardware that I might not need, I am hoping to find a solution using a voice recorder that I already own. Specifically, I own a SONY ICD-UX533, which has been great for the purposes I bought it for (recording lectures and interviews). However, I am unsure if there is a way to use it as an external microphone relative to another device such as my GoPro. It has both mic in and audio out jacks, but not mic out jack. I tried plugging both ports into my MacBook Pro and no external mic was detected. The mic has 4GB of internal storage, but I've put in a 32GB SD card as well. I guess I want to record audio directly to the GoPro SD card, or better yet split the audio and video among the two cards (to save space for video on the GoPro card) in a way that maintains their synchronicity. Might there be a way to hack this thing so that it can be used as an external mic? Or would I be better off doing all this in post-production? If the latter is the case, can someone please suggest a general workflow or series of best-practices that would help me do this effectively?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record on the GoPro using an external mic you need a mic adapter for the GoPro. This will let you use the audio out from your mic to plug in to the USB on your GoPro.

The alternative is to import video and audio separately into your video editor. This is a very common workflow pattern, and all you really require is a clapperboard or similar to sync up at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a cable from the phones out jack on the ICD recorder to the mic input on the GoPro? It might work, since you can monitor the recorded sound thru the headphone jack.